# Would a search bot have trouble with finding/indexing this link in PHP code from an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, php, html, indexing, bots

I wanted to make my site use more PHP in order to save space on HTML code and I wanted to try using this code to make a menu that would launch different `div`s containing different pages or information per se, I was wondering if search bots would have difficulty navigating such a maze because of php or Javascript or both?

Here's the code,

```
<?php
 if($_GET['button1']){fun1();}
 if($_GET['button2']){fun2();}

 function fun1()
 {
   //creates a div with a link to google
    echo'<a href = "http://www.google.com"><div style = "height:100px; width:20px; top:100px; left:100px; background-color: black;"></div></a>';   
 }
 function fun2()
 {
 //creates a div with a link to yahoo
   echo'<a href = "http://www.yahoo.com"><div style = "height:200px; width:40px; top:200px; left:200px; background-color: red;"></div></a>';
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btnfun1" name="btnfun1" onClick='location.href="?button1=1"'>Update to 1</button>
    <button id="btnfun2" name="btnfun2" onClick='location.href="?button2=1"'>Update to 2</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't count on it :). What's your problem with regular links?

Comment: The link is in the text - I think it will have no problem pulling it out. It may not understand the exact _relationship_ ("what was on the button that linked to x") but that's not really how search engines work anyway. Yet.

Comment: @kapa, nothing, I did explain why I'm dong this though, to make a single page with php updating the divs.

Comment: @Floris a *properly written* bot will only index links occurring in an `<a>` element containing an `href` component. Indexing just anything that looks like a URL is a great way to pull out a lot of useless information.

Comment: @Sammitch Ok, but will the bot run to php code to generate the html in order to index the anchor href?

Comment: @user2555139 But you can still keep the links, you can prevent their default action and do whatever you want with your JS.

Comment: @kapa You mean the links in the PHP code?

Comment: @user2555139 Forget the PHP code. It runs on the server. Bots only see the HTML document the server sent them (check View Source in your browser). If it finds an `<a href="">` in it, it will index and follow it. It is very easy. Btw, your PHP produces invalid HTML, echoing links before the doctype is not a good idea...

Comment: @Sammitch - you're right.

Comment: @kapa "Btw, your PHP produces invalid HTML, echoing links before the doctype is not a good idea" Not sure what you mean, how should I fix it, should a start another thread?

Comment: @user2555139 Sorry for this, but before being tricky you should learn the basics first. Without a good fundament you cannot really build a house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generally bots don't render JavaScript, so avoid that if you want those links indexed properly. Why are you even using onClick there?
2. PHP is not delivered to the client/bot, only its output which is generally HTML. So long as your output is valid the bots should crawl it just fine.

Comment: I'm using onclick to launch the php module, if you know of a bot search able way show that.

Comment: @user2555139 you're not. I don't think you're getting that PHP runs on the server, not the browser. Just use links.

Comment: Ok that answers it then. So bots don't following onclick events which use php to generate html?

Comment: @user2555139 bots are 100% unaware of PHP. The *server* runs the PHP and delivers the *output* to the client [aka the bot]. The server could be running literally any programming language under the sun, but the bot will never know, *it only gets the output*.